# How to document an entire sharepoint site?

Tags: 2007, document

I have been given the task of documenting my MOSS 2007 site.  What is the best way to go about documenting an entire sharepoint site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not to advertise or something but i've had excellent results with the following product SharePoint Documentation Toolkit (http://www.spdockit.com) which does the whole farm if needed to.

Beyond this, manually you could simply rely on SharePoint Designer for structure and depending on what exactly "documenting" means, you could envision looking at:

1. Site Topology (hierarchy, lists/libraries, themes)
2. Site Columns, content types, Lists/Libraries, both sub-site and
   whatever the site collection is pushing. Also you need to see
   Customized Forms and Pages. If it is a Publishing Site things get
   uglier (see complex), cause you need to identify Page Layouts used
   (which are always pushed from the Site Collection), and document relationships between page layouts/content types.
3. Features activated at the scope of your sub-site (SPWeb)
4. Web Parts used in page - particularly those customized and not OOTB
5. Files (aka Resources) - XSLTs mostly, images, CSS

This should give a head-start, also make sure you get Microsoft's worksheet on the Sharepoint site for more ideas.

Comment: Should I be concerned about documenting queries for each view?

Comment: if i'm not mistaken you are referring to the view definitions, depending on your deepness, yes, I would do it.

Answer (score 2):

I havent used this myself but it should work just fine! Its free too :)

http://spdocgen.codeplex.com/

Hope this helps :)